# Rotating the screen on the transitioned fragment saves the instances of the previous and transitioned fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've made a fragment transition from the fragment 1 to 2. In the fragment 2, I've rotated the screen. I've found that the method `onSaveInstanceState` is called for 2, then for 1. Is it a normal behavior, expected according to the Android SDK?

I've also found that after this screen rotation, in `onActivityCreated` that is of course recalled, `getArguments()` is not null and even contains the data that was given to the fragment 2 by the fragment 1 when the transition occurred. Is it also a normal behavior or did I do some mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments always save and restore their saved state, this includes Fragments that are on the back stack (such as your Fragment 1). Arguments are part of the saved state, so them being restored automatically is also the expected behavior.

Comment: Note: `onActivityCreated` seems to be called only on the current fragment, not on those that are on the back stack. Is it normal too?^^ if you say "yes", then it'd be clear I've found the reason of a bug and of the fix I've found! :)

Comment: Yes, `onActivityCreated()` happens right after `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`. Since Fragments on the back stack don't have their views created until you go back to them, `onActivityCreated()` isn't called until then. The name is rather confusing and a big reason why there's [plans to deprecate it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144309266)